# Keep calling a js function when hovering over button (html)

Tags: javascript, html

I have a button in my `html`file. I want to have a function called every x frames or seconds I hover over the button with my mouse. I did something with `setInterval` here but that's probably wrong. The current script changes the background to red once, after hovering over the button but that's all it does. I want it to call the function (and thus change the background) every x seconds.

```
function switchfunction(){
    if(document.body.style.background == 'red'){
        document.body.style.background = 'green';
    }

    else{
        document.body.style.background = 'red';
    }
}
var btn3 = document.getElementById("trolololol")
btn3.addEventListener("mouseover", function(){
    setInterval(function() {
        bdy.style.backgroundImage = "url('')";
        switchfunction();
    }, 500);
```

Comment: I'd recommend using adding a CSS class to the element to do this for you rather than doing it in JS.

Comment: What is the advantage of doing that? I've read that you should avoid coding things in the html file, or do you mean just move the style components to html and use code in js?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good way to handle this is with `setInterval()`, `onBlur` and `onHover`.

First... on hover:

```
var myHoverInterval = null;
var btn = document.getElementById("foo");

btn.addEventListener("mouseover", function() {
    if (myHoverInterval != null) {
        return;
    }
    myHoverInterval = setInterval(function() {
        console.log('Doing something');
    }, 1000);
});
```

to start executing the code.

Second... on blur:

```
btn.addEventListener("mouseout", function() {
    if (myHoverInterval != null) {
        clearInterval(myHoverInterval);
        myHoverInterval = null;
    }
});
```

to stop the interval from running again.

Comment: Thanks for the addition on how to make the flashing stop, this works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

For cases like this you, you have other options besides setInterval. One would be the requestAnimationFrame: https://mzl.la/1M5Be7I. If this doesn't work like you want, maybe because the delay between calls cannot be customized, I would suggest using cascading timeouts instead of an interval. Basically, you would use it like this:

```
let delay = 500, 
    timer = setTimeout(method, delay);
function method() {
  //.. do some thing here
  timer = setTimeout(method, delay)
}
```

And when you need to cancel, you can just do

```
clearTimeout(timer);
```

I favor this because, if needed, you can change the delay without having to close the interval and start a new one.

Answer (score 0):

You should store the result of `setInterval()` to avoid having multiple intervals at once

```js
var btn = document.getElementById("foo");
var interval;

btn.addEventListener("mouseover", function() {
  if(!interval)
    interval = setInterval(switchfunction, 500);
});

function switchfunction() {
  if (document.body.style.background === 'red') {
    document.body.style.background = 'green';
  } else {
    document.body.style.background = 'red';
  }
}
```

```html
<button id="foo">Hover me!</button>
```

Comment: 1) it doesn't stop; 2) it stacks if you hover multiple times (and make my eyes hurt)

Comment: @NoOorZ24 OP did not ask to stop it

Comment: "Keep calling a js function **when hovering over button** (html)

"

Comment: @NoOorZ24 Following my code, when you hover the button it will keep calling `switchfunction()` every 500ms. That is what OP asks

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear enough in my post then. I only want it to keep flashing while you hover over the button. No restrictions on how to achieve this,

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using CSS to achieve this rather than doing this in JavaScript, see the below snippet on how to do this.

```css
.button:hover~.bg {
  background: red;
  animation: myfirst 1s;
  /* Firefox */
  -moz-animation: myfirst 1s infinite;
  /* Safari and Chrome */
  -webkit-animation: myfirst 1s infinite;
}


/* Firefox */

@-moz-keyframes myfirst {
  0% {
    background: red;
  }
  50% {
    background: green;
  }
  100% {
    background: red;
  }
}


/* Firefox */

@-webkit-keyframes myfirst {
  0% {
    background: red;
  }
  50% {
    background: green;
  }
  100% {
    background: red;
  }
}

.bg {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
  background: #EEE;
}
```

```html
<input type="submit" value="submit" class="button" />
<div class="bg"></div>
```

This, however, does require you to add another element on the page.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to close the function; This is also needed to be removed.

```
document.body.style.backgroundImage="url('')";
```

I have no idea what exactly you would like to use that for. For now when you hover on the button the background colour start flashing between two different colours. You also can comment the green background colour and switch between the background-colour and the background-image.

```js
function switchfunction(){
    if(document.body.style.background == 'red'){
        document.body.style.background = 'green';
      //document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url('http://i.imgur.com/FV5EnXhb.jpg')";
    }else{
        document.body.style.background = 'red';
    }
}
var btn3 = document.getElementById("trolololol");
btn3.addEventListener("mouseover", function(){
    setInterval(function() {       
        switchfunction();
    }, 500);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div >
    <h1>TESTING</h1>
    <button id="trolololol">HOVER</button>
  </div> 
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.0.0.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: But how to let it stop the flashing when the mouse leaves the button?